# Ошибка: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Задача: написать функцию для изменения таймфрейма на кодировках.

Тело программы:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from future_functions import *

# Load CSV Data

data = pd.read_csv('Data/Hours.csv')

data.columns = ['Date','open','high','low','close','AskVol']

data = data.set_index(pd.to_datetime(data.Date))

data = data[['open','high','low','close','AskVol']]

prices = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

hkaprices = prices.copy()
hkaprices['Symbol'] = 'SYMB'

HKA = OHLCresample(hkaprices,'15H')
```

, где `future_functions` - подключеный файл с функцией.

Сама функция:

```
def OHLCresample(DataFrame,TimeFrame,column='ask'):


    grouped = DataFrame.groupby('Symbol')

    if np.any(DataFrame.columns == 'Ask'):

        if column == 'ask':
            ask = grouped['Ask'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
            askVol = grouped['AskVol'].resample(TimeFrame).count()
            resampled = pd.DataFrame(ask)
            resampled['AskVol'] = askVol

        elif column == 'bid':
            bid = grouped['Bid'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
            bidVol = grouped['BidVol'].resample(TimeFrame).count()
            resampled = pd.DataFrame(bid)
            resampled['BidVol'] = bidVol

        else:

            raise ValueError('Column must be a string. Either ask or bid')

    elif np.any(DataFrame.columns == 'close'):
        open = grouped['open'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
        close = grouped['close'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
        high = grouped['high'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
        low = grouped['low'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
        askVol = grouped['AskVol'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()

        resampled = pd.DataFrame(open)
        resampled['high'] = high
        resampled['low'] = low
        resampled['close'] = close
        resampled['AskVol'] = askVol

    resampled = resampled.dropna()

    return resampled
```

Получаю ошибку:

> KeyError: 'AskVol'
>
> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Понимаю, что проблема в размерности, но не знаю как решить.

Comment: Не знаю как вам можно помочь без примера данных, который поможет воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: Не знаю как тут приатачить файл но датасет выглядит так:
6 колон --> Gmt time,Open,High,Low,Close,Symbol с соответствующими данными --> 12.06.2018 00:00:00.000,1.17729,1.17736,1.17413,1.17531,10137.79
........
По сути можно взять кодировки с любого места

Comment: можно указать URL на данные... можно выложить на файлообменнике... Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1` говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь присвоить одному столбцу матрицу / DataFrame  с четырьмя столбцами.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [24]: new_data = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4))

In [25]: new_data
Out[25]:
array([[8, 3, 6, 1],
       [6, 8, 5, 1],
       [4, 6, 9, 2]])

In [26]: new_data.shape
Out[26]: (3, 4)

In [27]: df['new'] = new_data
...
skipped
...
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1
```